# R Applying rules to timestamps in one column based on value in another to facilitate filtering

Tags: r, timestamp

The verbiage of this situation is a little tricky for me, so I apologize if it is a duplicate. I searched for a solution based on my best understanding of the desired output

Suppose I have this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555),
                 A = c('2020-04-13 19:10:00', '2020-04-14 20:00:00', '2020-04-13 19:10:00', '2020-04-14 20:00:00',
                       '2020-04-22 08:13:00', '2020-04-23 19:00:00', '2020-04-13 19:10:00', '2020-04-14 20:00:00',
                       '2020-04-22 08:13:00', '2020-04-23 19:00:00', '2020-04-27 13:41:10', '2020-05-01 22:01:00'),
                 B = c('2020-04-15 12:00:00', '2020-04-15 12:00:00', '2020-04-24 11:00:00', '2020-04-24 11:00:00',
                       '2020-04-24 11:00:00', '2020-04-24 11:00:00', '2020-05-07 10:30:00', '2020-05-07 10:30:00',
                       '2020-05-07 10:30:00', '2020-05-07 10:30:00', '2020-05-07 10:30:00', '2020-05-07 10:30:00')
)

df$A <- as.POSIXct(df$A)
df$B <- as.POSIXct(df$B)


> df
    ID                   A                   B
1  555 2020-04-13 19:10:00 2020-04-15 12:00:00
2  555 2020-04-14 20:00:00 2020-04-15 12:00:00
3  555 2020-04-13 19:10:00 2020-04-24 11:00:00
4  555 2020-04-14 20:00:00 2020-04-24 11:00:00
5  555 2020-04-22 08:13:00 2020-04-24 11:00:00
6  555 2020-04-23 19:00:00 2020-04-24 11:00:00
7  555 2020-04-13 19:10:00 2020-05-07 10:30:00
8  555 2020-04-14 20:00:00 2020-05-07 10:30:00
9  555 2020-04-22 08:13:00 2020-05-07 10:30:00
10 555 2020-04-23 19:00:00 2020-05-07 10:30:00
11 555 2020-04-27 13:41:10 2020-05-07 10:30:00
12 555 2020-05-01 22:01:00 2020-05-07 10:30:00
```

I would like to filter down to one row for each distinct value of column B with the corresponding minimum value of A, with the requirement that the value of A is greater than the preceding value of column B, if any. So the desired output would be reduced to:

```
> df
   ID                   A                   B
1 555 2020-04-13 19:10:00 2020-04-15 12:00:00
2 555 2020-04-22 08:13:00 2020-04-24 11:00:00
3 555 2020-04-27 13:41:10 2020-05-07 10:30:00
```

In this scenario, there would be many more IDs, so ID and B would be the grouping variables. Is this possible with dplyr?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by minimum value of A and that A is greater than B ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(previous_B = lag(B, default = as.POSIXct(0, origin = '1970-01-01'))) %>%
  group_by(B, .add = TRUE) %>%
  filter(A > first(previous_B)) %>%
  summarise(A = min(A)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(ID, A, B)

#    ID    A                   B                  
#  <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
#1   555 2020-04-13 19:10:00 2020-04-15 12:00:00
#2   555 2020-04-22 08:13:00 2020-04-24 11:00:00
#3   555 2020-04-27 13:41:10 2020-05-07 10:30:00
```

Filter those rows in the data in which `A` is higher than the last value of `B` in previous group. After that you can just keep the minimum `A` value in each group.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your solution :

```
my_df <- data.frame(ID = c(555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555),
                A = c('2020-04-13 19:10:00', '2020-04-14 20:00:00', '2020-04-13 19:10:00', '2020-04-14 20:00:00',
                      '2020-04-22 08:13:00', '2020-04-23 19:00:00', '2020-04-13 19:10:00', '2020-04-14 20:00:00',
                      '2020-04-22 08:13:00', '2020-04-23 19:00:00', '2020-04-27 13:41:10', '2020-05-01 22:01:00'),
                B = c('2020-04-15 12:00:00', '2020-04-15 12:00:00', '2020-04-24 11:00:00', '2020-04-24 11:00:00',
                      '2020-04-24 11:00:00', '2020-04-24 11:00:00', '2020-05-07 10:30:00', '2020-05-07 10:30:00',
                      '2020-05-07 10:30:00', '2020-05-07 10:30:00', '2020-05-07 10:30:00', '2020-05-07 10:30:00')
)

my_df$A <- as.POSIXct(my_df$A)
my_df$B <- as.POSIXct(my_df$B)

my_df$Time <- str_split(string = my_df$A, pattern = " ", n = 2, simplify = TRUE)[, 2]
my_df$Time2 <- str_split(string = my_df$B, pattern = " ", n = 2, simplify = TRUE)[, 2]

my_result <- my_df %>% group_by(ID, B) %>% filter(Time > Time2) %>% filter(Time == min(Time))
```

I let you try with all your data and let me know if it give you the expected result